# How to nest entities in DDD

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

I am having StudentDriver as aggregate root. Each StudentDriver may have multiple DrivingLogs and each DrivingLog may hold multiple DrivingRecords.

Since they are connected to eachother I think it is right. However I don't understand how if I am going to add a new drivingrecord for instance. Do I invoke studentdriver.addNewDrivingRecordToDrivingLog(...) or do I first get a drivinglog from the user and then add the drivingrecord to this. I mean, the method names are getting really long and I don't understand how you are supposed to access elements.

Could someone explain how you are supposed to interact with the members of StudentDriver, and even if this aggregate is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I invoke studentdriver.addNewDrivingRecordToDrivingLog(...) or do I first get a drivinglog from the user and then add the drivingrecord to this. I mean, the method names are getting really long and I don't understand how you are supposed to access elements.

Looks like getting DrivingLog instance and then adding record to it would be better, but this really seems to be on of those things that you should figure out on your own because we don't know enough about you domain. Both approaches don't violate any DDD rules. Try one and change it later if you don't like it (i.e. code smells, tests are hard etc). DDD code should be continuously improved along with your understanding of the domain. There is really no right or wrong in this situation.

Comment: So there is not anything wrong with getting hold of entites etc inside an aggregate root as long as other aggregate roots don't have them? Like, putting the entites together outside of the aggregate root isn't bad?

Comment: I mean, since the StudentDriver is the aggregate root it is not bad to constuct the drivinglog outside of the studentdriver and add drivingrecords directly on the drivinglog and then attach the drivinglogs to the user before it is persisted etc throguh the repository? When having aggregates it doesn't mean that you can't still access things inside it?

Comment: And one last thing: When you for example add a drivinglog to a studentdriver, then you need to update the studentdriver in the repository right? You don't have own repositories for entites in aggregates? So everytime something in the studentdriver aggregate changes you must "update" the studentdriver?

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. I bought the DDD book and haven't got further than chapter 2. Does it teach you these things?

Comment: It does. But I find it more useful to have a specific problem and search for the answer in the book, as oppose to just reading it from cover cover and putting on a shelf. You do need to read it all eventually, and maybe even more than once.

Comment: So you would recommend that I use it more as an reference now in the start for my application than reading the whole at once? And then later read it cover to cover?